# Sub Category Radio Buttons in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, macros

I have a word document I send to users. In the document there are **two groupings** of ActiveX radio buttons for users to choose from. I use radio buttons because each of the selections must be mutually exclusive with an exception.

The second group of radio buttons must be sub-options of one of the radio buttons from the first group (i.e.; mutually exclusive to each other, but available when only one of the radio buttons in the first grouping is selected).

For example if my form were being used to order a type of fruit and these were my choices:

```
Set 1 Fruit:

Option1 - Oranges - deselected

Option2 - Bananas - deselected

Option3 - Strawberries - deselected

Option4 - Kiwis - deselected

Option5 - Apples - selected
```

I would have a second set for the type of apple that looked like this:

```
Set 2 Type of Apple:

Option1 - Honey Crisp - selected

Option2 - Golden Delicious - deselected
```

but if anything other than Apple were selected in group 1, group 2 would look like this:

```
Set 2 Type of Apple:

Option1 - Honey Crisp - deselected

Option2 - Golden Delicious - deselected
```

I offered to management that there be a third radio button in the second group for "N/A" unless the correct radio button in the first group is chosen but they do not want this. They want the second group of radio buttons to be blank if anything but Apple is chosen in the first group.

I've done a little digging and find this...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50910935/how-to-enable-a-text-box-depending-on-radio-button-groups-by-vba-in-word

None of it really seems to help me and because this form is being distributed to users and for security reasons, management also doesn't like VBA/Macros as an option.

Is there a way to do this without macros? Is there a built in control that behaves in this manner? I don't believe check boxes are an option because those in group 2 have to be mutually exclusive and check boxes can't behave in this manner without macros.

I can set the default value to both radio buttons in the second group to false, but is there a way to set or toggle them to false for the user without the developer tab, or having to close the document and reopen it?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm afraid you'd need some `VBA` for this. An alternative would be to use combo-boxes with a list of options, pulled from a range of values.

Comment: Being able to use VBA would make this so much easier, and I suggested combo boxes (even use one elsewhere in the form) but management doesn't like that either. They want the user to see all of their options for this particular set. It would be way easier if radio buttons had a toggle switch for the default value or check boxes had a mutually exclusive option in groupings. I guess I'll push the combo box for the sub categories again and see where I get. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The ActiveX OptionButton (radio button) has a property of `Value`. Can you not set `Value` to True for one radio button in each frame?

Comment: Yes but users aren't going to have access to the developer tab to do this on their own for the most part, nor will many of them want it.  I would set the default to false and if they clicked accidently or saved over the template form, they'd have to figure out how to get them both unchecked. Need an easier solution and it looks like either a macro or a drop down management will have to be happy with,. Or maybe something else entirely different.